# Ensuring ADA compliance

Tags: accessibility

We are implementing web accessibility in our Sitecore solution to make our website ADA compliance.

When working with general links, including value in the **alt** field of link puts this value in **title** attribute on the page.

[image: Link in Description]

[image: Link on Page]

Is this enough to achieve ADA compliance for links? 
We are using NVD tool to check screen reader if it'll read the title attribute and it does not.

Also, is there any Sitecore module we can use to achieve web accessibility in Sitecore so that we don't have to extend default Sitecore fields?

Comment: What level of ADA compliance? WCAG 2.0, 2.1 and what level? A, AA, AAA - there are so many variables, I don't think you could get a true answer here. You really need to use a checking tool for your site. I have used SiteImprove a lot and they have a Sitecore plugin: https://siteimprove.com/en-gb/core-platform/integrations/cms-plugin/sitecore/ - seems to work well in my experience.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSeal for the reply. We are only starting with web accessibility and will be using WCAG 2.0. Having said that, I have little knowledge on what changes are required to make websites web accessible to some extent. I will try out the module you mentioned and will update here on it.

Comment: You can pass the accessibility check and still have issues - saying that you can fail and not have the issues it states you do - only manual checking will clear you.